# Emacs I want to call execute-kbd-macro from a lisp function

Tags: emacs, macros, keyboard, elisp

I want to call a keyboard macro from a Lisp function. I hope to layer in some custom error handling.

`mykey` is a keyboard macro stored in a text file in `(fset ...)` format.
I loaded it with `load-file` and it works fine when called with `M-x mykey`.

When I execute this function and plug in `mykey` I get only the name of the key displayed in current buffer, not it's execution. Is there a step I'm missing?

```
(defun gn-batch-search (key-name)
  "Execute a keyboard macro that has already been loaded."
  (interactive "sName of macro key:")
  (execute-kbd-macro key-name))
```

Comment: Side note: `load-file` is an interactive command.  When writing Elisp code, you may as well use `load` which is shorter and does otherwise the same.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
(defun gn-batch-search (key-name)
  "Execute a keyboard macro that has already been loaded."
  (interactive "sName of macro key:")
  (execute-kbd-macro (intern key-name)))
```

The issue you bumped into is that the `"sName of macro key:"` interactive spec prompts the user and returns a *string*, and you want to run the *command* whose name is described by this string.  That explains why it didn't do what you wanted and why you need `intern`.

As for why it did what it did: a keyboard macro is represented as a vector of *events*, where events can be things like mouse clicks or key presses.  And as it turns out, a string is considered as a kind of vector (a vector characters) and a character is also an event (it represents the event that is sent when you press that character on your keyboard), so the string `"hi"` is a valid keyboard macro which represents the act of pressing <kbd>h</kbd> followed by pressing <kbd>i</kbd>, so when you run this macro, it will (usually) end up inserting "itself" in the current buffer (except in special buffers like dired, `*Help*`, ... where <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>i</kbd> are bound to other commands).

Also, rather than `execute-kbd-macro` you can use `command-execute` which will work with "any" command, whether it's defined as a keyboard macro or a normal function.

Comment: Thank you so much! The (intern key-name) did the trick. As you suggested it also works with command-execute. Wondering why none of the examples I saw in the docs ever mentioned having to intern the symbol? Maybe other commands done earlier in sequence on keyboard macros had that built-in?

Comment: c meade: Interning is only needed to make a *symbol* out of a *string*, which in turn is only relevant if you are trying to pass a symbol as the `MACRO` argument to `execute-kbd-macro`. Presumably none of the examples you saw were using this combination.

Comment: Thank you phils. That makes sense. Macros are pretty unusual animals.

Comment: c meade: Note that you should 'accept' an answer if it has resolved your question.